# Updating unique views using cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a forum thread file `thread.php` that gets topic ID information.

Example:

`thread.php?id=781`

I'm trying to create a unique views setup, but I have no idea if this is actually feasible:

**`thread.php`:**

```
topicId = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>;

if ($.cookie("unique"+topicId)!=="1") {
    $.cookie("unique"+topicId,1,{expires: 1000, path: '/'}); // create cookie if it doesn't exist
    $.post('unique.php',{id:topicId}); // update thread unique views
}
```

**`unique.php`**

```
// connection stuff

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE topics SET unique_views=unique_views+1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

This will create a new cookie for each different thread. So if the user views 100 threads, they'll have 100 cookies stored. I'm worried if creating a new cookie for each thread is too much. Is that okay or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even being possible, that is a waste of resources. You should serialize your data into a single cookie using JSON, for example.

In Javascript you can encode your topics array into a JSON string with **JSON.stringify**:

```
$.cookie("cookie_name", JSON.stringify(topicsId_array));
```

Then you can get the data with **JSON.parse**:

```
var topicsId_array = JSON.parse($.cookie("cookie_name"));
```

Remember you can use the **push** JS method to add elements to an array (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp), so you could get the data from the cookie add the new Id with push and then save it with stringify.

To finish, you should care about duplicates. If you don't want them when using push, you can use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ to clear the array or use a own JS function such as:

```
function unique(array_source)
{
    var array_destination = [];
    var found = false;
    var x, y;

    for (x=0; x<array_source.length; x++)
    {
        found = false;
        for (y=0; y<array_destination.length; y++)
        {
            if (array_source[x] === array_destination[y])
            {
              found = true;
              break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            array_destination.push(array_source[x]);
        }
    }
   return array_destination;
}

var topicsId_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa'];
topicsId_array = unique(topicsId_array);
```

And in the end, something like this should work:

```
var topicsId_array = JSON.parse($.cookie("cookie_name"))
topicsId_array.push("your_new_id");
topicsId_array = $.unique(topicsId_array);
$.cookie("cookie_name", JSON.stringify(topicsId_array));;
```

Comment: Just a question - since it needs to check if the topicId is set with the value "1" within that one large cookie and also actually needs to store the cookie value of "1", how would I do that and set up the if statement?

Comment: Ok, for me if you want only to save the topics visited, you should use an id array like **var topicsId_array = [1, 2, 4, 26];** (simple and efficient), so in the array only should remain the topics that are set to 1 (and delete the others). But if you that is not your case and you need to store additional data (such as number of views or anything else), you can use an array of objects and store all what you want. Stringify will also work pretty well. Here you have an example: [http://jsfiddle.net/y11zLra7](http://jsfiddle.net/y11zLra7)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, cookies are a part of the HTTP protocol, and are being sent over the wire with every HTTP request, and since the request has a size limit, at a certain point it will exceed that size and will cause inconsistent browser behavior, regardless of it you use many small cookies or one large cookie.

I would chose a solution other than a cookie - most likely I would persist it on the server side